# android app cannot resolve host

Tags: java, android, ksoap2

I'm developing an application in android which connects to a wcf service and returns the results.The wcf is written with soap and I'm using KSOAP2 for connecting.

At first I was connecting to a certain url and everything was working nicely. Then I had to change the url and I get an unknown exception `unable to resolve host:No address associated with name`.

I've done my research and the solution to all the other similar problems was adding in the Android Manifest internet connection. But I've done that already .Any suggestions? Another detail is that using the first url ,in which my application was working fine, is a normal url the second is in a local server ,by the way though my pc is connected properly in this server.(properly meaning that when i use the url with my browser has no problem connecting with it )

I'm posting here the class which establishes the connection:

public class KSoapConnector implements InstantiateConnection{

```
private SoapObject response;
private WcfReceivedClass identifier;
private WcfReceivedClass[] receivedData;    
private final String NAMESPACE = "http://microsoft.com/webservices/";
private String METHOD_NAME="GetTeacherClass";         
private String SOAP_ACTION = "http://microsoft.com/webservices/IVertiSchool_SRV/GetTeacherClass";
private final String URL = "http://vertiserv1:81/VertiSchool_SRV.svc";

    //below is the url which was working fine
//private final String URL = "http://wcf.schoolportal.gr/VertiSchool_SRV.SVC";



public  KSoapConnector(String methodName,int mode){





    SoapObject Request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

    //here are the parameters for the wcf service and there values are correctly put   
    Request.addProperty("connString", "connectionString");
    Request.addProperty("TeCode", "tCode");
    Request.addProperty("Company", "cmp");
    Request.addProperty("Lng", "lng");
    Request.addProperty("MainPeriod", "mainPrd");


    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    envelope.dotNet = true;
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(Request);      
envelope.addMapping(NAMESPACE, "SRV_Class",new SRV_Class().getClass());
HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);


    try{

        //here is where i get the exception...
        androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);

        response = (SoapObject)envelope.getResponse();

        receivedData = identifier.retrieveFromSoap(response);
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

}

and here is my manifet file :

```
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     package="com.example.myapp"
     android:versionCode="1"
     android:versionName="1.0" >

        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />  

 <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" /> 

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>        
    <activity android:name=".ListOfClasses"></activity>            
</application>
```

I know that in Android the localhost is 10.0.2.2 but my application connects straigth to the local server...should i forward any ports?

Comment: Could you be specific code-wise?

Comment: You are able to connect to url using the phone's browser?

Comment: @subirkumarsao i haven't tried that but is it relevant since i was able to connect properly with the other url?

Comment: @subirkumarsao i've tried to launch my browser and it works fine..But this still didn't fix my problem

Comment: What i suspecting as i said before is that the url i'm using is local  but i don't know if this is really an issue since my browser in my pc will open it with no problem...

Comment: Ok i searched a bit more, see the problem is that my pc is in the local network so it can access the server normally, my virtual device though doesn't belong in this network.Do you know how can i connect the avd to my local network?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

ok i've found out what was the problem..Apparently this url wasn't able to be resolved by my app but it was due to that website's binding so i will contact the admin.

Answer (score 0):

Your SOAP_ACTION should be something like this.

```
AppConsts.NAMESPACE =  "http://www.tempuri.us/"

usecaseString = THIS SHOULD BE YOUR METHOD NAME OF SERVICE.

String soapAction = AppConsts.NAMESPACE + usecaseString;
```

And your URL should be something like this.

```
NAMESPACE+/PROJECTNAME/SERVICE_NAME.asmx
```